# Assigning a hash as association to an object fails if the hash has id, need to understaand why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash with id which I want to assign as association to an object, I get this error

```
{"amount"=>nil, "base_currency_amount"=>nil, "currency_id"=>1, "deal_product_id"=>nil, 
"expected_close"=>"2021-06-02", "id"=>3, "name"=>"test", "product_id"=>nil}

(byebug) new_record.deal = current_properties["deal"]
*** ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Exception: Couldn't find LeadDeal with ID=3 for Lead 
with ID=

nil
```

But when I remove the ids from the hash, it works

```
(byebug) new_record.deal = current_properties["deal"].except("id")
{"amount"=>nil, "base_currency_amount"=>nil, "currency_id"=>1, "deal_product_id"=>nil, "expected_close"=>"2021-06-02", "name"=>"test", "product_id"=>nil}
(byebug) new_record.deal
#<LeadDeal id: nil, account_id: 1623836761, name: "test", amount: nil, expected_close: "2021-06-02", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, deal_product_id: nil, currency_id: 1, base_currency_amount: nil, product_id: nil>
```

I thought it's because the new_record is missing id, but even if I add the id it fails with this error

```
(byebug) new_record.id = 3
3
(byebug) new_record.company = current_properties["company"]
*** ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Exception: Couldn't find LeadCompany with ID=3 for Lead with ID=3

nil
```

all the values are present in db, and it works as expected if I just remove ids from the hash, I want to know why this happens

Comment: How does the implementation of `new_record.deal=` look like? What is a `LeadDeal `?

Comment: Lead and LeadDeal are classes with 1 to 1 association, id as foreign_key, delegated as deal

Comment: Is `deal` really an association or a method on `Lead`? Assigning a hash to an association should result in an `AssociationTypeMismatch` error, so what you are showing doesn't make sense unless `deal` is some kind of method that takes a hash does something with it.